# Error when running Memgraph 2.1.1 on MacBook Air with M1

Tags: docker, memgraphdb

I want to run Memgraph 2.1.1 inside Docker. I have MacBook Air with M1. When I try to run it I get the error:

```
> docker run -p 7687:7687 memgraph/memgraph
WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8) and no specific platform was requested
You are running Memgraph v2.1.1
To get started with Memgraph, visit https://memgr.ph/start
qemu: uncaught target signal 6 (Aborted) - core dumped
```

In my docker log I can see also some errors:

```
memgraph@e01736c43b23:/usr/lib/memgraph$ cat /var/log/memgraph/memgraph_2023-02-13.log
[2023-02-13 11:16:17.124] [memgraph_log] [warning] Invalid license key string. To use Enterprise features please set it to a valid string using the following query:
SET DATABASE SETTING "enterprise.license" TO "your-license-key"
[2023-02-13 11:16:17.254] [memgraph_log] [warning] No snapshot or WAL file found. For more details, visit https://memgr.ph/durability.
[2023-02-13 11:17:50.221] [memgraph_log] [warning] Using non-secure Bolt connection (without SSL). For more details, visit https://memgr.ph/ssl.
[2023-02-13 11:18:03.589] [memgraph_log] [critical]
Assertion failed in file /memgraph/src/utils/async_timer.cpp at line 144.
    Expression: 'timer_create(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &notification_settings, &timer_id_) == 0'
    Message: 'Couldn't create timer: (22) Invalid argument'
```

What can I do to start Memgraph in docker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to upgrade Memgraph to newer version. Support for M1 was added in [Memgraph 2.2](https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph/changelog#v220---feb-18-2022).